# How to Count Total Number of Records and Display?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "select count(userId) from tblUser";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$link)or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM); 
echo $row[1];
```

print_r($row); is displaying no of records but whu echo is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need **[`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)**

```
echo mysql_num_rows($result);
```

That'll give you number of rows return from query.

<strike>If, however, you are using the `count` keyword in your query, you should modify your code like this:</strike>

```
$sql = "select count(userId) as total from tblUser";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['total'];
```

**Update:**
You can also count total users like this:

```
$sql = "select userId from tblUser";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
echo mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: it will give `1` because I have used `count`(userId).

Comment: That will show the number of rows brought back (1 in this case) which would be incorrect. If pamela had a query like `select userId from tblUser` it would then do what I assume she's looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_array` is zero counted. You will want to `echo $row[0];`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about the array index?

```
echo $row[0];
```